# Remove specific string between two strings in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

Excuse me for my bad English.

I have large text file and I want to delete specific codes other than meaningful sentences.

[]meaningless codes that i want delete them, contain "_" absolutely and between two frames  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqk41.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqk41.png

i use \�.*?� *(� character is that frame\square. i did'nt copied in post.)* but it results sentences that i dont want delete. because this code dont concerns "_" character.

Comment: I think you look for this: `�[^�]*_.*?�`.

Comment: IMHO it's an encoding problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the condition that you use the actual special character in your regular expression, you just need to extend it so that it also matches at least one underscore. While doing that, you need to make sure you do not unintentionally skip over an ending � character, so that's why you'll need `[^�]*` in there:

`�[^�]*_.*?�`